# Ubuntu going full-GUI

Tags: gui

Do you see anytime in foreseeable future, Ubuntu going full GUI?
I'm a new user on Ubuntu and I can see everything is done through Terminal (and I love it) but, This could be a drawback for newbie people who tend to use their computers "normally" from installing Linux and they would stick forever to their Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is already at the stage where many people may never need to use a terminal. You can install and remove software from the GUI, you can choose to only use graphical software, and you can configure all that software using menus and preferences in the software's UI.

For example, if all you want to do is use the web, email, word processing, spreadsheets, and so on, you may never need to use the terminal.

Comment: Let's compare troubleshooting as an example between Linux and Windows, If you google your problem, the workarounds you find on the internet mostly tell you to use Regedit, gpedit or going thorugh settings through control panel etc. which are all GUI. If you try to resolve your issue --like here on askubuntu-- most if not all instructions tell you to run commands through Terminal, and not understanding the commands that you're running could be scary, because on GUI everything is explained and you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

We still have Server version, so terminal will stay.
Advancing GUI will only benefit Ubuntu by expanding the customer base and attracting more uses. And terminal still a part of of GUI - not everything should be duplicated in UI (the same for the Windows - the most advanced scenarios are possible via PowerShell only)

Comment: "the most advanced scenarios"  like what?! O.o

Comment: managing networks (routing) for example. no way to do it via UI